# Bootstrap 4 masonry item to span multiple columns using card-columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm reading upon the *[masonry](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-columns)* layout for Bootstrap 4 using `card-columns` and it works great, but would it also be possible for a masonry *item* to span multiple columns, as well? Right now, it seems that every item is restricted to its own column without having the flexibility of *spanning* two columns or more. I drew a little sketch to help clarify my question a bit better:

[image]

In this sketch, you can see that the blue item is spanning more than one column while the other items are positioned in their respective column. I took a look at the `column-count` CSS property, but I wasn't sure how this is helpful in this situation. So is this possible with the Bootstrap 4 masonry grid layout using `card-columns`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are the items all the same height? If they are you don't need to use card columns/masontry

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just have to *nest* another `card-columns` for it to work.

```
.card-columns
  .card // Item 1
  .card // Item 2
  .card-columns // Item 3 and 4 card-columns wrapper
    .card // Item 3
    .card // Item 4
  .card // blue item
```